# Is there a way to integrate Alipay with Squarespace?

Tags: payment-gateway, squarespace, alipay

I am building an online store on Squarespace and I want my customers to have the option to check out with AliPay. How do I do it? I want people to choose whether to check out by Credit Card or AliPay.